# How to trigger specific font when changing language?

Tags: keyboard, font, language

I use Pages as my main word-processing application and regularly have to type in both English and Greek. I use either Times New Roman or Hoefler Text in English and GFS Porson for Greek. Is there a way to automatically trigger a specific font (in this case, GFS Porson) anytime I switch over to the Greek keyboard?

Comment: This is not an answer for your actual question, but might solve your need.  Have you considered finding a typeface with both good latin characters and good greek?  For example, many of the Adobe "Pro" fonts support Latin and Greek (e.g. Text Pro, Minion Pro, Garamond Pro...)

Answer (score 1):

Pages doesn't itself have a way to do that exactly, but the app Nisus Writer does, via preference settings.

In Pages I'd recommend creating "styles" for Greek and English in your preferred fonts.  Styles can be attached to keyboard shortcuts.